# Count lines for a particular string combination

Tags: c#

I am trying to count no. of lines in which ProductServices and Add Product are appearing.

Logs are :

> INFO [ProductServices] Add Product has been performed by gulanand on
>   product with id 424 ()  INFO [ProductServices] Add Product has been
>   performed by gulanand on product with id 424 ()  INFO
>   [ProductServices] Add Product has been performed by gulanand on
>   product with id 424 ()  INFO [ProductServices] Update Product has been
>   performed by gulanand on product with id 424 ()  INFO
>   [ProductServices] Update Product has been performed by gulanand on
>   product with id 424 ()  INFO [ProductServices] Add Product has been
>   performed by gulanand on product with id 424 ()  INFO
>   [ProductServices] Add Product has been performed by gulanand on
>   product with id 424 ()  INFO [ProductServices] Add Product has been
>   performed by gulanand on product with id 424 ()

Code i have tried is :

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines =
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Ashish Logs\", "*.*")
                        .Select(filePath => File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
                        .SelectMany(line => line);

List<string> users = new List<string>();

Regex r = new Regex(@"*ProductServices\sAdd Product");
foreach (string Line in textLines)
{
    if (r.IsMatch(Line))
    {
        users.Add(Line);
    }
}
//string[] textLines1 = new List<string>(users).ToArray();
int countlines = users.Count();
Console.WriteLine("ProductsCreated=" + countlines);
```

Comment: And *how* does your code not work?

Comment: what is the problem? what is your exact question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this: (for each file)

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
int count = lines.Count(input => input.Contains("ProductServices") && 
                                 input.Contains("Add Product"));
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
 int count = File.ReadAllLines().Count(x=>x.Contains("MONKEY"));
```

Linq is Luvly!